# Target based members in ANTLR4

Tags: java, c++, python-3.x, antlr4

Is there a way to distinguish language targets and provide appropriate version of @members in a grammar file?  Different language targets use different comment and syntax.  I would like to maintain the same grammar file for different target languages.

For Cpp (C++) target:

```
@members {
  // C++ target:
  bool a_boolean = 0;
}
```

For Python3 target:

```
@members {
  # Python target:
  a_boolean: bool = True
}
```

For Java target:

```
@members {
  /** Java target:
   */
  Boolean a_boolean = true;
}
```

Or are there any ANTLR4 meta conditionals that can check the target language?  This is my own syntax, but is there something line this?

```
@members {
  $if Cpp
    // C++ target:
    bool a_boolean = 0;
  $fi

  $if Python
    # Python target:
    a_boolean: bool = True
  $fi

  $if Java
    /** Java target:
     */
    Boolean a_boolean = true;
  $fi
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing of that is possible. It's a simple copy-paste operation which ANTLR4 performs on parser generation, including all whitespaces like indentation + line breaks.

The only option you have is to distinguish between C++ and all other targets, because for C++ I have introduced [additional named actions](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/cpp-target.md#named-actions), like `@parser::definitions`.

However, if you add something to a named action like `@members`, which appears in all targets, then you will end up with non-C++ code in your resulting files (when using C++ as target).

So in sum, your approach will not work and you better use a different solution, like a base class for parser and lexer, which contain the member variables you need. For details search for:

```
options {
    superClass = ...;
}
```